# Javascript: Значение радио кнопки при клике

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть форма:

```
<div id="browsers">
  <p><b>Браузер:</b><Br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" value="ie"> Internet Explorer<Br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" value="opera"> Opera<Br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" value="firefox"> Firefox<Br>
  </p>
```

Как с помощью JavaScript (без использования библиотек вроде jQuery) узнать значение `value`, если пользователь кликнул на радио кнопку?

Т.е. при клике на `Internet Explorer` в консоли 'ie', при клике на `Opera` - 'opera'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var check = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){
    check[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         alert(this.value)
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но нужно на JavaScript без использования библиотеки jQuery

Comment: @Pavel, переписал на js

Comment: спасибо Вам! Отлично работает!

Comment: Как-то не так переписал - код на jQuery делал не то же самое, что этот.

Comment: @Qwertiy, простите что?

Comment: @cheburashkarf, в коде на jQuery был один обработчик, повешенный на контейнер (использовалось всплытие). Аналогичный ему код в моём ответе. А в "переписанном" варианте вешается 3 обработчика на сами радиобаттоны.

Comment: @Qwertiy , Мне не понятно что такое переписанный вариант,ответ то я дал раньше вас уж извините.Вы предложили другой вариант,Всегда хорошо иметь несколько ответов,что не так то?

Comment: @cheburashkarf, у этого ответа есть 3 [версии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/564390/revisions) - вторая содержит вариант с jQuery, а третья - текущая. Так же есть комментарий: _"переписал на js"_ - без него я бы в ревизии и не полез смотреть. Я говорю о том, что на jQuery-код из второй ревизии похож код в моём ответе. А код в этом ответе не эквивалентен jQuery-коду, поскольку вместо использования всплытия вешает несколько обработчиков. А про то, кто из нас и как раньше ответил, я ничего вообще не говорил.

Comment: Ответы про html/css/js отлично смотрятся, когда код завёрнут в сниппет и его можно выполнить прямо в ответе. Посмотрите, как в двух соседних ответах сделано.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById("browsers").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  document.getElementById("selected-browser").textContent = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
label { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="browsers">
  <h3>Браузер (<output id="selected-browser">?</output>)</h3>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser" value="ie"> Internet Explorer</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser" value="opera"> Opera</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser" value="firefox"> Firefox</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Плюс за единственный нормально работающий сниппет.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function radioClick(radioItem){
 alert(radioItem.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="browsers">
  <p>
    <b>Браузер:</b>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser[]" value="ie" onclick="radioClick(this);"> Internet Explorer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser[]" value="opera" onclick="radioClick(this);"> Opera<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser[]" value="firefox" onclick="radioClick(this);"> Firefox<br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но нужно input должны быть без  onclick="radioClick(this);". Т.е. нужен аналог jquery: $("#browsers").on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function(){}